# Вопрос по поводу many to many в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Здравствуйте. У меня есть 2 сущности.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students")
    private List<Teatcher> teatchers = new ArrayList<Teatcher>();
}
```

и

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "teatcher")
public class Teatcher {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany(cascade =  CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_teatcher"
            , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "teatcher_id")}
            , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "student_id")})
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
}
```

Вот так я их заполняю:

```
    Teatcher teatcher1 = new Teatcher();
    teatcher1.setName("teatcher1");

    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.setName("student1");
    student1.getTeatchers().add(teatcher1);

    teatcher1.getStudents().add(student1);
```

У меня появляются записи во всех 3ех таблицах (student, student_teatcher,  teatcher), только если сохраняю так:

```
objectService.save(teatcher1);
```

И появляются записи только в одной таблице (student), когда я сохраняю так:

```
objectService.save(student1);
```

Почему, когда я сохраняю teatcher, появляются записи во всех 3ех таблицах(student, teatcher, student_teatcher), а если student, то только в таблице student. Я попробовал поиграться с cascade и mappedBy, но у меня ничего не выходит.

Comment: Что значит получается правильно? Неправильно это как?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: согласен, поправил вопрос.